# Create an index of the content of each file in a folder

Tags: python, search

I'm making a search tool in Python.

Its objective is to be able to search files by their content. (we're mostly talking about source file, text files, not images/binary - even if searching in their METADATA would be a great improvment). For now I don't use regular expression, casual plain text.

This part of the algorithm works great !

The problem is that I realize I'm searching mostly in the same few folders, I'd like to find a way to build an index of the content of each files in a folder. And be able as fast as possible to know if the sentence I'm searching is in xxx.txt or if it can't be there.
The idea for now is to maintain a checksum for each file that makes me able to know if it contains a particular string.

Do you know any algorithm close to this ?

I don't need a 100% success rate, I prefer a little index than a big one with 100% success.
The idea is to provide a generic tool.

**EDIT** : To be clear, I want to search a PART of the content of the file. So making a md5 hash of all its content & comparing it with the hash of what i'm searching isn't a good idea ;)

Comment: it would help if your provided some more information, some code - your environment, some examples...

Comment: The idea is to provide a generic tool. Tell me if you don't understand something in my question. If you want example, open every text files in any folder of you HDD, how would you improve the search of a sentence in all their content ? (in order to know witch file & at witch line he does containt it)

Comment: its not that i dont understand what you want. but StackOverflow is not a place where you come and request something and come back a day later and copy-paste the code into your project. if i said "i need to program x y z kthxbai" no one would help me, but if i come and say "hello everyone, i tried x y z, it isnt working, im trying to achieve a b c, and so far i am having luck with 1 2 3..." as you understand. its clear to me what you want, but how exactly can i help you?

Comment: "Do you know any algorithm close to this ?"
I actually don't need the code, just looking for a clever algorithm to do this. I don"t make this to really sovle a particular problem, just to make a Opensoruce tool
The idea I'm working on now is "The idea for now is to maintain a checksum for each file that makes me able to know if it contains a particular string." but I didn't find any working ways.

Comment: For now I try to associate each word with a prime number based on the char used and make a file checksum by multiplying them togather. I do the same on each word of the search query, if they can divide the checksum, thei're in the file. But that's not really working great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the most efficient, but just uses the stdlib and a little bit of work. sqlite3 (if it's enabled on compilation) supports full text indexing. See: http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html

So you could create a table of [file_id, filename], and a table of [file_id, line_number, line_text], and use those to base your queries on. ie: how many files contain this word and that line, what lines contain this AND this but not etc...

Comment: Sqllite will really makes me win lot of time compared to doing it directly ? (Open each file and search in them). It seems a good idea but the index will be bigger than the content indexed :s

Comment: @iggy Well, you'll have overhead involved in putting your data in sqlite to start with, but after that, it'll all be indexed, so queries should be quick and easy to execute. For instance, you'll be able to look for the word "Python" and straight away (or pretty much hopefully) get a list of files/line numbers it appears on

Comment: That's cool, but the only problem is if I wanna do this on 50go of files, I'll have to use 50go for index :s

Comment: @iggy Maybe look at http://lucene.apache.org/core/ or similar - if you want fast general searching (short of some specialised list of keywords/etc... - in which case you could use a bitmap I guess)

Answer (score 6):

here i am using whoosh lib to make searching/indexing.. .upper part is indexing the files and the lower part is demo search.. .

```
#indexing part

from whoosh.index import create_in
from whoosh.fields import *
import os
import stat
import time

schema = Schema(FileName=TEXT(stored=True), FilePath=TEXT(stored=True), Size=TEXT(stored=True), LastModified=TEXT(stored=True),
                LastAccessed=TEXT(stored=True), CreationTime=TEXT(stored=True), Mode=TEXT(stored=True))

ix = create_in("./my_whoosh_index_dir", schema)
writer = ix.writer()



for top, dirs, files in os.walk('./my_test_dir'):
    for nm in files:
        fileStats = os.stat(os.path.join(top, nm))
        fileInfo = {
            'FileName':nm,
            'FilePath':os.path.join(top, nm),
            'Size' : fileStats [ stat.ST_SIZE ],
            'LastModified' : time.ctime ( fileStats [ stat.ST_MTIME ] ),
            'LastAccessed' : time.ctime ( fileStats [ stat.ST_ATIME ] ),
            'CreationTime' : time.ctime ( fileStats [ stat.ST_CTIME ] ),
            'Mode' : fileStats [ stat.ST_MODE ]
        }
        writer.add_document(FileName=u'%s'%fileInfo['FileName'],FilePath=u'%s'%fileInfo['FilePath'],Size=u'%s'%fileInfo['Size'],LastModified=u'%s'%fileInfo['LastModified'],LastAccessed=u'%s'%fileInfo['LastAccessed'],CreationTime=u'%s'%fileInfo['CreationTime'],Mode=u'%s'%fileInfo['Mode'])

writer.commit()


## now the seaching part
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    query = QueryParser("FileName", ix.schema).parse(u"hsbc") ## look for files with 'hsbc' in their name
    results = searcher.search(query)
    for x in results:
        print x['FileName']
```

Comment: I'll have a look at whoosh in the night.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason anyone would want a tool that is capable of searching 'certain parts' of a file is because what they are trying to do is analyze data that has legal restrictions on which parts of it you can read.

For example, Apple has the capability of identifying the GPS location of your iPhone at any moment a text was sent or received. But, what they cannot legally do is associate that location data with anything that can be tied to you as an individual.

On a broad scale you can use obscure data like this to track and analyze patterns throughout large amounts of data. You could feasibly assign a unique 'Virtual ID' to every cell phone in the USA and log all location movement; afterward you implement a method for detecting patterns of travel. Outliers could be detected through deviations in their normal travel pattern. That 'metadeta' could then be combined with data from outside sources such as names and locations of retail locations. Think of all the situations you might be able to algorithmically detect. Like the soccer dad who for 3 years has driven the same general route between work, home, restaurants, and a little league field. Only being able to search part of a file still offers enough data to detect that Soccer Dad's phone's unique signature suddenly departed from the normal routine and entered a gun shop. The possibilities are limitless. That data could be shared with local law enforcement to increase street presence in public spaces nearby; all while maintaining anonymity of the phone's owner.

Capabilities like the example above are not legally possible in today's environment without the method IggY is looking for.

On the other hand, it could just be that he is only looking for certain types of data in certain file types. If he knows where in the file he wants to search for the data he needs he can save major CPU time only reading the last half or first half of a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple name-based cache as below.  This is probably best (fastest) if the file contents is not expected to change.  Otherwise, you can MD5 the file contents.  I say MD5 because it's faster than SHA, and this application doesn't seem security sensitive.

```
from hashlib import md5
import os

info_cache = {}

for file in files_to_search:
    file_info = get_file_info(file)
    file_hash = md5(os.path.abspath(file)).hexdigest()
    info_cache[file_hash]=file_info
```

Comment: Sorry maybe my question wasn't clear on this part (I edited it), I want to search a PART of the content of the file. So making a md5 hash of all it's content & comparing it with the hash of what i'm searching isn't a good idea ;)

Comment: How does that help in searching? From what I understood from OP, what is required for the application is something that would index the file contents, or did I not understand correctly?