# how can i build my custom search engine for desktop pc with python

Tags: python, linux, search

I am thinking of using python and Django for building the custom search engine.
I have following ideas

- Python script will walk through all the directories break the file into following fields
- 1. path
  2. filename
  3. Extension
  4. size

I will store that in Django Model

Then i can make the simple with search filters.
I don't want to go in the contents. i just want to search by the filename only

Python script i am thinking of using the
`os.walk`

is that ok , or i need to use more methods as well

Comment: People usually expect more from a search box than just filename -- for example, are you going to support searching _in the middle_ of the name? How about inside the files?

Comment: You could add some regex support, searching files that match a regex.

Comment: You should definitely use the `os.path` module as well, especially `os.path.split` and `os.path.splitext`

Comment: I just want to keep it simple , just the filename and thats for my personal computer at home. and yes i want to search using the levenshtein distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this post by me; it is using `whoosh` to generate index of files; then you can use it in your django/flask.. . 
 
[Create an index of the content of each file in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497607/create-an-index-of-the-content-of-each-file-in-a-folder/13498458#13498458)

you can also replace the `whoosh` with `sqlite3`